# Undefined index in custom field?

Tags: members, error, custom-fields

I'm getting the following error when I turn on debugging.

```
Notice
Undefined index: m_field_ft_3

ee/legacy/libraries/channel_entries_parser/components/Custom_member_field.php, line 120
```

I don't get this error on the home page, but on individual story pages. This is from EE v 3.5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is missing a field in database. When you create a new member field, It creates two fields in DB under `exp_member_data` table.

1. m_field_id_1
2. m_field_ft_1

Your 1 field is there but ft field is missing. To solve this, Either you can delete the field from backend and create a new one or go to DB and create `m_field_ft_3` field. (Use data type as **TinyText**)

Comment: That solved the problem, although I'm troubled that this field was missing.

Comment: Its weird why the field didn't created by default. Did you use anything other then a default member field creation page at backend or any extension call on member field creation?